# I got error in react while using normal javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am working on react-flow, and my task is to transform the following data => `

```js
`const configObj = {
    name: "Dataset",
    nodeChild: {
        type: "schema",
        nodeConfiguration: {
            sid1: {
                name: "Schema 1",
                nodeChild: {
                    type: "dashboard",
                    nodeConfiguration: {
                        did1: {
                            name: "Dashboard 1"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            sid2: {
                name: "Schema 2",
                nodeChild: {
                    type: "dashboard",
                    nodeConfiguration: {
                        did2: {
                            name: "Dashboard s1",
                        },
                        did3: {
                            name: "Dashboard 3"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}` to this -> 
const elements = [
  {
    id: '1',
    type: 'input', // input node
    data: { label: 'Input Node' },
    position: { x: 250, y: 25 },
  },
  // default node
  {
    id: '2',
    // you can also pass a React component as a label
    data: { label: <div>Default Node</div> },
    position: { x: 100, y: 125 },
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    type: 'output', // output node
    data: { label: 'Output Node' },
    position: { x: 250, y: 250 },
  },
  // animated edge
  { id: 'e1-2', source: '1', target: '2', animated: true },
  { id: 'e2-3', source: '2', target: '3' },
];
```

`
not exactly but according to data1 so i prepare a code for it and it is working well in node environment but the moment i try it on react it shows some error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PssLk.png)  here is my code

```js
const configObj = {
  name: "Dataset",
  onClick: true,
  nodeChild: {
      type: "schema",
      nodeConfiguration: {
          sid1: {
              name: "Schema 1",
              nodeChild: {
                  type: "dashboard",
                  nodeConfiguration: {
                      did1: {
                          name: "Dashboard 1"
                      }
                  }
              }
          },
          sid2: {
              name: "Schema 2",
              nodeChild: {
                  type: "dashboard",
                  nodeConfiguration: {
                      did2: {
                          name: "Dashboard s1",
                          nodeChild: {
                              type: "ritik",
                              nodeConfiguration: {
                                  ri1: {
                                      name: "Ritik",
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      },
                      did3: {
                          name: "Dashboard 3"
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }, 
}

let count =1;
let dataConfig = []

const recursion = (obj, level,type) => {
  let objData = {}
  for(let j in obj){
      if(j !== 'nodeChild' && j !== 'nodeParent'){
          if(j === 'name'){

              objData= {
                  ...objData,
                  label: obj[j] 
              }

          }else {
          
              objData= {
                  ...objData,
                  [j]: obj[j] 
              }
          }
          
      }
  }

  let idd = count
  dataConfig = [...dataConfig, {id: count, data: objData, type, level, parentID}]
  count++;

  if('nodeChild' in obj){
      const {nodeConfiguration, type} = obj.nodeChild
      for(let val in nodeConfiguration){
          recursion(nodeConfiguration[val], level+1, type, parentID = idd)
      }
  }

  if('nodeParent' in obj){
      const {nodeConfiguration, type} = obj.nodeParent
      for(let val in nodeConfiguration){
          recursion(nodeConfiguration[val], level-1, type)
      }   
  }
}
recursion(configObj, level=0, type='root', parentID=1)

let edges = []
for(let i=1; i<dataConfig.length; i++){
  let e = {
      id: `e${dataConfig[i].id}-${dataConfig[i].parentID}`,
      source: `${dataConfig[i].parentID}`, target: `${dataConfig[i].id}`, animated: true 
  }
  edges = [
      ...edges,
      e
  ]
}


let finalDataSet = []
let x=650, y=25;
let flag = false;
for(let i in dataConfig){
  let element = {}

  for(let key in dataConfig[i]){
      if(key !== 'parentID'){
          if(key === 'type'){
              let k = dataConfig[i][key]
              if(k === 'schema' || k === 'root'){
                  element = {
              ...element,
              [key]: 'input'
          } 
              }else {
                  element = {
              ...element,
              [key]: 'output'
          } 
              }
          }else {
              element = {
              ...element,
              [key]: dataConfig[i][key]
          } 
             
      }
          }
      
  }
  element = {
      ...element,
      position: { x, y }
  }

  // console.log(i)
  finalDataSet = [
  ...finalDataSet,
  element
  ]

  y += 75;
  if(!flag){
      x = 25;
  }
  x = flag ? x+155 : x
  flag = true
}
for(let i =0; i<edges.length; i++){
  finalDataSet = [
      ...finalDataSet,
      edges[i]
  ]
}

const DataSET = finalDataSet
export default DataSET
```

this code is perfectly working on local nodejs but the same code pops errors on react.js can any one help me on this

Comment: Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the `recursion(configObj, level=0, type='root', parentID=1)` calls that are causing trouble. You think that `level=0` is saying to pass `0` to the `level` parameter but javascript doesn't recognize that syntax. It thinks that `level` is some variable you forgot to define. Hence the `is not defined` error.

To fix the issue, just do something like `recursion(configObj, 0, 'root', 1)` instead.

Comment: No, it didn't help me, i try but problem remain same